# Deploy non-project files from TFS (2010) to a folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have several files added to TFS which is not part of any VS solution, and I'd like to have any check-in for these files to trigger a deploy of the file(s) to a folder on a specific server.

Looking into the TFS Build configuration to solve this, but the default template requires items to build. In my case, there is nothing to build, only files to be copied from TFS to a specific folder.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with TFS Build Configuration? Are there any other approaches to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom build process template to handle this scenario. Ideally, you'd upgrade to TFS 2017 and take advantage of the new build and release systems that were introduced in TFS 2015, as they are designed to make non-standard scenarios easier to achieve.

[Mainstream support for TFS 2010 ended in July 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/03/06/mainstream-support-for-tfs-2010-ends-in-july/), so it's in your organization's best interest to invest in an upgrade.